# AngularCli - Angular development flow too slowly

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to know why the angular development workflow using *angular-cli* is so slow?

I'm using `watchman`, and everything else, but, it takes at least 3/4 seconds turn.
What is the reason? It depends on Typescript? is the Ember-cli?